# WPF-Horizontal scroller not displaying in Listview

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, scrollview, horizontal-scrolling

I am working on WPF application.I am new WPF. I Used Listview in my application showing below image:-

[image]

My XAML is :-

```
  <ListView x:Name="lstviewMeters"  BorderThickness="1"   Height="263" Margin="0,89,23,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="597" AlternationCount="2" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
             <ListView.View>
                <GridView >
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Feeder Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MeterName}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MeterID}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Status" Width="120"  >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}"/>
                                    <Image Width="16" Height="16" Source="{Binding IconUri}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="TimeStamp" Width="120"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TimeStamp}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Remark" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Remark}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

I changed style of default scrollbar for make decent look for UI, For that I create resource dictionary and call it in XAML. The issue is vertical scrollbar is visible but horizontal scroll is not showing when the cell content is extended.It should be visible when  I expand the cell manually.
I have set below property  for scroller but still not working

```
 <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
```

Can anyone have solution for this to always visible  both VSCROLL and HSCROLL

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Simply surround your ListView with ScrollViewer like:

```
  <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
       <ListView>.....</ListView>
  </ScrollViewer>
```